# Deserialize nested(n-level) json to C# objects using Newtonsoft dll

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am consuming an API that gives me a multi level JSON, I want to convert it into C# object. Any help will be appreciated.

JSON

```
{
  "Categories": [
    {
      "Code": "2984",
      "Name": "Baby",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Code": "100978",
          "Name": "Christening & Gifts",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Code": "100980",
              "Name": "Baby Jewellery"
            },
            {
              "Code": "100981",
              "Name": "Ornaments"
            },
            {
              "Code": "121628",
              "Name": "Gift Baskets"
            },
            {
              "Code": "139760",
              "Name": "Christening",
              "Children": [
                {
                  "Code": "100979",
                  "Name": "Gifts"
                },
                {
                  "Code": "139764",
                  "Name": "Silverware"
                },
                {
                  "Code": "139765",
                  "Name": "Other Christening"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Code": "32871",
              "Name": "Other Gifts"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Code": "100982",
          "Name": "Baby Carriers/Backpacks"
        },
        {
          "Code": "1261",
          "Name": "Other Baby"
        },
        {
          "Code": "134282",
          "Name": "Walkers"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Try using http://json2csharp.com/ to convert this json into a bunch of C# classes

Comment: What is the question? Don't reply "How to deserialize this string". If your classes match the JSON format, you won't need anything more than `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRootClass>(..)`. Are you asking how to create the target classes?

Comment: Sylence, tried this. But it gave me 6 objects, which is not recommended as I am not sure if there is a fixed number of level or not.

Comment: Panagiotis, Yes I was asking the target class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that Json string is invalid. It's missing the array termination character for the first category's Children. The string should end like this:

```
        }]
    }]
}
```

After fixing this typo, you can use any classes that match the string's structure, eg:

```
class MyRoot
{
    public Node[] Categories {get;set;}
}

class Node
{
    public string Code{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Node[] Children{get;set;}
}

var myRoot=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRoot>(someString);
Console.WriteLine(myroot.Categories[0].Children[3].Name);

------
Walkers
```